# Django blog engine that pulls posts from github?

Tags: python, django

Is there a blog engine that runs on Django (or at least python) that pulls the blog posts from github?

I really like the idea of [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), which does this in Ruby, but would prefer a python/django solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for in python is called [hyde](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hyde/).

Comment: Thank you! I guess it's not a "blog engine" hence my failure to find it while googling.